# Different WAR files, shared same user permission

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, seam

I have in a EAR two different .WAR files(A.war and B.war). The EAR file is deployed in an JBOSS server 4.0.5

Currently I have defined in A.WAR several user with their own permissions.
In A.war the user is able to navigate to some screen that are stored in B.WAR( some JSF screen from B are embedded in A ) . The problem that I have is I need to check in B.WAR the current user and their permissions. All this data is assigned in A.war.

How can I say to B what is the user than is accessing?

How is possible to share the user permission between WAR files? It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable SSO, as detailed here: [JBoss7 Web SSO (Non-Clustered)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471591/jboss7-web-sso-non-clustered) or here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/configuring-single-signon-on-jboss-as-7

Add `sso` tag to your `standalone.xml`:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
    ...
    <sso domain="local" reauthenticate="false"/>
</virtual-server>
```

And add/update your `war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml`:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>sso</security-domain>
    <valve>
        <class-name>org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn</class-name>
    </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do your approach